reshape data.frame with duplicate values
I have data frame called sample_df as below:
sample_df <- data.frame(
  date = c("2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27", "2023-02-27"),
  weight = c(121.56, 459.25, 114.02, 459.25, 298.0, 56.78, 446.85, 215.05, 459.25, 114.02, 579.84, 189.96, 84.4, 446.85, 215.05, 298.0, 56.78, 459.25),
  marker = c("weight_log", "weight_log", "weight_log", "weight_log", "weight_log", "weight_log", "weight_log", "weight_log", "weight_bc", "weight_bc", "weight_bc", "weight_bc", "weight_bc", "weight_bc", "weight_bc", "weight_bc", "weight_bc", "weight_bc")
)

         date weight     marker
1  2023-02-27 121.56 weight_log
2  2023-02-27 459.25 weight_log
3  2023-02-27 114.02 weight_log
4  2023-02-27 459.25 weight_log
5  2023-02-27 298.00 weight_log
6  2023-02-27  56.78 weight_log
7  2023-02-27 446.85 weight_log
8  2023-02-27 215.05 weight_log
9  2023-02-27 459.25  weight_bc
10 2023-02-27 114.02  weight_bc
11 2023-02-27 579.84  weight_bc
12 2023-02-27 189.96  weight_bc
13 2023-02-27  84.40  weight_bc
14 2023-02-27 446.85  weight_bc
15 2023-02-27 215.05  weight_bc
16 2023-02-27 298.00  weight_bc
17 2023-02-27  56.78  weight_bc
18 2023-02-27 459.25  weight_bc

I want to convert sample_df to become result_df as below:
         date weight_log weight_bc
1  2023-02-27     459.25    459.25
2  2023-02-27     459.25    459.25
3  2023-02-27     121.56        NA
4  2023-02-27     114.02    114.02
5  2023-02-27     298.00    298.00
6  2023-02-27      56.78     56.78
7  2023-02-27     446.85    446.85
8  2023-02-27     215.05    215.05
9  2023-02-27         NA    579.84
10 2023-02-27         NA    189.96
11 2023-02-27         NA     84.40

I've tried to use reshape2::dcast, but the result is not like what I expected.
sample_df %>% reshape2::dcast(date + weight ~ marker,value.var = "weight") %>% select(-weight)
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
         date weight_bc weight_log
1  2023-02-27         1          1
2  2023-02-27         1          0
3  2023-02-27         1          1
4  2023-02-27         0          1
5  2023-02-27         1          0
6  2023-02-27         1          1
7  2023-02-27         1          1
8  2023-02-27         1          1
9  2023-02-27         2          2
10 2023-02-27         1          0

I guess it's because there's duplicate weight value.
Is there another way to convert sample_df to become result_df?

One way is to first differentiate the duplicated weight values per marker and then add a group id that groups the similar weights
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sample_df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number(), .by = c(marker, weight)) %>% 
  mutate(grp = cur_group_id(), .by = weight) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = marker, values_from = weight) %>% 
  select(-c(rn, grp))
# A tibble: 11 × 3
   date       weight_log weight_bc
   <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2023-02-27      122.       NA  
 2 2023-02-27      459.      459. 
 3 2023-02-27      114.      114. 
 4 2023-02-27      459.      459. 
 5 2023-02-27      298       298  
 6 2023-02-27       56.8      56.8
 7 2023-02-27      447.      447. 
 8 2023-02-27      215.      215. 
 9 2023-02-27       NA       580. 
10 2023-02-27       NA       190. 
11 2023-02-27       NA        84.4


This one works. Thanks!
